# What is christmas loot?

Tags: meaning

Im learning whats loot and ive seen is like to steal or stolen things 
But is Christmas loot like gifts stolen? Or is an idiom

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like it's "loot" in the video game sense rather than the military sense. Like when you kill a boss and they drop loot. So yeah, maybe it's just an idiom for "presents"

Comment: This exact example is in the dictionary: ["3. a collection of valued objects:
The children shouted and laughed as they opened their Christmas loot."](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/loot)

Comment: It's nearly always *Christmas **swag***, not ***loot***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I'm kind of puzzled by that assertion - for one things, a  Google Books search for *[Christmas loot](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Christmas+loot%22)* returns almost twice as many results as *[Christmas swag](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Christmas+swag%22)*, and a lot of the second group are clearly used in the sense of "something hanging, as a decoration, between two points."

Comment: @stangdon: I'm kinda puzzled myself. When I wrote that comment it reflected *my* experience - but I distinctly remember doing a very brief check (on either NGrams or Google Books) which confirmed my belief, even though I didn't put a link in the comment. I usually add an extra word or two to reduce "accidental collocations", so maybe it was [*our Christmas **swag***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22our+Christmas+swag%22) (80 GB hits, compared to 40 for ***loot***). But I can't argue the point now I see NGrams says there are NO hits at all for case-insensitive "christmas swag".

Answer (score 2):

It is a joking expression for the large number of presents that many children get for Christmas. The joke is the kids are greedy just like pirates, but there is no suggestion that they have stolen anything. It's meant affectionately because most grownups remember feeling that way themselves. And it can be extended to presents for grownups too.